# MongoDB Aggregation, group by subobject keys

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection whose schema looks like this:

```
_id: ObjectId(),
segments: {
  activity: 'value1',
  activation: 'value2',
  plan: 'value3'
}
```

I'm trying to use the aggregation framework to find out how many of my documents have the value1 for the segment activity for instance.

The problem is that I want to do that for every segment in the same request if possible, and that I don't know how many segments I'll have or even their name.

Basically here's what I'd like to do:

If I have these two documents:

```
{ _id: 1, segments: { activity: 'active', activation: 'inactive', plan: 'free' }
{ _id: 2, segments: { activity: 'inactive', activation: 'inactive', plan: 'free' }
```

I want to be able to see that two of them have the activation segment to inactive and the free plan, and that activity have 1 inactive and 1 active values. Here is what I want to get:

```
{ 
  activity: {
    active: 1,
    inactive: 1
  },
  activation: {
    inactive: 2
  },
  plan: {
    free: 2
  }
}
```

So basically, if you could just `$group` by key it would be great! Something like this:

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: { $concat: [ '$segments.$key', '-', '$segments.$key.$value' ],
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
}
```

Or if I could unwind on each key...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the counts, take advantage of the [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator in the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) pipeline step to evaluate the counts based on the subdocuments value, something like the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([    
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": "$_id",             
            "activity_active": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$segment.activity", "active" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "activity_inactive": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$segment.activity", "inactive" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "activation_active": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$segment.activation", "active" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "activation_inactive": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$segment.activity", "inactive" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "plan_free": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$segment.plan", "free" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            } 
        }  
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,            
            "activity": {
                "active": "$activity_active",
                "inactive": "$activity_inactive"
            },
            "activation": {
                "active": "$activation_active",
                "inactive": "$activation_inactive"
            },
            "plan": {
                "free": "$plan_free"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Ok, so there's no way of doing that if I don't know the different possible values nor the different possible keys?

Comment: @JulienFouilhé No other way I know through the aggregation framework unless you do another query with mapReduce to get the dynamic keys list and using the distinct() method to return a list of possible values, then you can generate a pipeline dynamically using those queries.

Comment: I think I'll do a query for each segment (I'm using mongoose so I can access the schema to get them and do: `{ $group: { _id: '$segments.activity', count: { $sum: 1 } }` but thanks! That's what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 0):

there could be a generic solution to this problem, but might need a bit post processing:

to get output similat to this:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "activity" : "active",
        "activation" : "inactive"
    },
    "plan" : [{
            "type" : "free",
            "total" : 1
        }, {
            "type" : "paid",
            "total" : 1
        }
    ]
}, {
    "_id" : {
        "activity" : "inactive",
        "activation" : "inactive"
    },
    "plan" : [{
            "type" : "free",
            "total" : 1
        }
    ]
}, {
    "_id" : {
        "activity" : "inactive",
        "activation" : "active"
    },
    "plan" : [{
            "type" : "paid",
            "total" : 3
        }, {
            "type" : "free",
            "total" : 6
        }
    ]
}
```

> use query like that:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
            $group : {
                _id : {
                    activity : "$segments.activity",
                    activation : "$segments.activation",
                    plan : "$segments.plan"
                },
                total : {
                    $sum : 1
                }
            }
        }, {
            $group : {
                _id : {
                    activity : "$_id.activity",
                    activation : "$_id.activation"
                },
                plan : {
                    $push : {
                        type : "$_id.plan",
                        total : "$total"
                    }
                }
            }
        },

    ])
```